# Weak convergence improved by Morrey embedding

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $u_n: [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a sequence with
\begin{equation}
u_n \rightharpoonup u \ \ \ \text{weakly star in } L^2(0,T;W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3))
\end{equation}

and $\eta : [0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ continuous in time. Assume further $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\psi \in L^2(0,T)$. Now it says

\begin{equation}
\int _0^T (u_n(t, \eta(t,x)) - u(t, \eta(t,x))  ) \psi dt \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}

and I'm not sure if I understand why this is true. I think this follows from the Morrey embedding, which states that $W^{1,\infty }(\mathbb{R}^3) \subset C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is a compact embedding for $\alpha < 1$. What confuses me is that $\eta$ depends also on $t$ but I think this does not matter as the convergence in $C^0$ is uniform, we should have something like

\begin{equation}
\int _0^T (u_n(t, \eta(t,x)) - u(t, \eta(t,x))  ) \psi dt \leq \int _0^T \sup_{y}|u_n(t, y) - u(t, y)  | \psi dt \rightarrow 0
\end{equation}

although I'm not sure if this can be written like that. Is this argument correct?

Comment: $W^{1,\infty}$ is the space of Lipschitz functions, so you don't need to apply Morrey embedding.

Comment: But I think we need the compactness of the embedding to obtain the convergence uniformly in the second argument of $u_n$, right? Otherwise we only have the weak-star convergence and I don't think that this is enough